# DBMS_SCHEDULER JOB interval not working

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, jobs

I've created `DBMS_SCHEDULER` job, which type is `CHAIN`. Chain has 2 steps and 2 rules. Each step has PL/SQL "program" (which inserts `SYSDATE` to table). First rule's condition is `TRUE`. Second rule has condition checks if step 1 is completed and then runs second step. After I enabled `CHAIN` and `JOB`, then `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS` table shows `SUCCEEDED` for both chain steps. Table keeping date has new values. So I would say that chain has ran successfully.

Problem here is that `JOB` does not execute second time. Job is suppose to run every 5 minutes.

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name          => 'RUN_REFRESH',
    job_type          => 'CHAIN',
    job_action        => 'QUICK_REFRESH_CHAIN',
    repeat_interval   => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=5',
    start_date       => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    enabled      => TRUE
);
END;
/
```

Job is also active in `DBA_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS` table.

Additional info:

```
SELECT START_DATE, LAST_START_DATE, NEXT_RUN_DATE 
FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS 
WHERE job_name = 'RUN_REFRESH'; 

shows: 
21.01.2015 12:58:18,000000000   
21.01.2015 12:58:18,328107000   
21.01.2015 12:58:18,000000000
```

Questions:

1. Does `DBA_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS` show only currently running
   jobs instead or enabled/scheduled jobs?
2. Why doesn't `JOB` run second time, even though `CHAIN` ran
   successfully?

Answer (score 1):

If a job has to run in an interval, the job needs to be in the state 'SCHEDULED' in between. In case of a job chain, make sure that it actually has an ending, otherwise it will remain running forever.

1. DBA_RUNNING_JOBS only shows the jobs that are in state 'RUNNING'
2. make sure the chain has an END action.